# UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h not found when running React Native app in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a simple React Native app that I've been testing on Android and now want to test on iOS. It's using React Navigation.

I ran `npm run ios` but I'm getting the following error:

```
info In file included from 

/Users/rbbit/reactnative/testproj1/ios/testproj1/main.m:10:

/Users/rbbit/reactnative/testproj1/ios/testproj1/AppDelegate.h:9:9: fatal error: 'UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h' file not found

#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

info 1 error generated.
```

I opened XCode but I'm basically getting the same message, nothing else that would help me debug this.

I do see that there is a package called react-native-adapter (https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/%40unimodules/react-native-adapter), however I'm hesitant to just install this since I followed the instructions on how to include react-navigation and didn't mention that, assuming this is related.

Also, that page says `If you are using react-native-unimodules, this package will already be installed and configured!`, and `react-native-unimodules` already is in my dependencies.

Any pointers on how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For latest RN versions (RN 0.60+) errors like this should be fixed with the auto-linking and just running a `pod install`.

For older versions you should try:

`react-native link` in the root folder of your project

Then in `Xcode Product->Clean Build` folder, restart JS server and attempt to rebuild.

If still not working double check the configs from here:

https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules

and the `App.delegate` from here:
https://gist.github.com/brentvatne/1ece8c32a3c5c9d0ac3a470460c65603

Sources:

Pod install reminder was first suggested by Sandy in the below comment

Comment: Hi Florin! `react-native link` didn't fix it. Also, I don't have a pod file at all in my XCode project (as expected in the links you included). Is it possible to have an XCode project without Cocoapods at all?

Comment: Actually, I was going to create a Podfile and noticed that it exists, but was hidden. So following the steps from the link worked. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have a project without any CocoaPods. I am happy the steps worked. :)

Comment: For anyone that runs into this, what was missing was to run a `pod install`

Comment: I had to install cocoapods (see https://cocoapods.org/) and then `cd ios; pod install`.  I believe cocoapods is not generally needed for react native now but if you're using any module that uses `react-native-unimodules` (such as `react-navigation`) then it's needed.

Comment: @Sandy it worked like a charm, this was simple yet elegant solution, thanks a loads man

Comment: After upgrade from react native `0.62.2` to `0.63.2` I am getting this error

Answer (score 14):

`pod install` didn't work for me until I added these lines to my pod file:

`require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'`

And

`use_unimodules!(modules_paths: ['../node_modules'])`

Then do a `pod install`.

Example: https://gist.github.com/sjchmiela/6c079f2173938a9a61a7c6f053c45000

Comment: you nailed it sir

Comment: That did it indeed, however know that `react-native-unimodules` has been deprecated as of Oct 2021. Source: https://blog.expo.dev/whats-new-in-expo-modules-infrastructure-7a7cdda81ebc

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error with everything configured correctly, everything in the other answers done and all the [unimodules installation steps](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/) already done, on a project that had worked for months, building it on a new computer. It turned out the reason was because I was simply using the wrong file in xCode.

I had opened  the `.xcodeproj` file when I should have opened and run the build from the **`.xcworkspace`** file.

Everything seemed to work as normal apart from this error, which made it look like a configuration problem rather than a simple "you opened the wrong file" problem. Hopefully if someone else makes the same mistake, this will save them a few hours of fruitless tinkering.