# about 'UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h' file not found

Tags: react-native

I am developing with React native.
However, I am currently experiencing the following build error, which has not been resolved.
'UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h' file not found
I have also checked the article on Stackoverflow, but it has not been resolved.
[UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h not found when running React Native app in iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745352/ummoduleregistryadapter-h-not-found-when-running-react-native-app-in-ios-simulat)
If there is any other information you need, please let me know.

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'


target 'xxxxxx' do
  target 'xxxxxxx-stg'
  target 'xxxxxxx-dev'
  # Pods for xxxxxxx
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  use_unimodules!

  target 'xxxxxxxTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  use_native_modules!

  static_libraries = ['RNPermissions', 'Permission-Camera']

  pre_install do |installer|
    # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
    installer.pod_targets.each do |target|
      if static_libraries.include?(target.name)
        def target.build_type;
          Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library
        end
      end
      if target.name == "UMPermissionsInterface"
        # https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6477
        target.dependent_targets << installer.pod_targets.select{|t| t.pod_name == 'UMCore'}.first
      end
      if target.name == 'UMReactNativeAdapter'
        target.dependent_targets << installer.pod_targets.select{|t| t.pod_name == 'React-CoreModules'}.first
      end
    end
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if ['RNFBApp', 'RNFBMessaging'].include?(target.name)
        target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'GoogleUtilities'})
      end
      if ['RNFBCrashlytics'].include?(target.name)
        target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'Fabric'})
        target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'Crashlytics'})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

thank you.